# Re-creating NPER in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math

For specifically the formula below, I tried recreating it as a method named `nper` inside one of my models.  The calculations aren't resulting as expected (testing using the NPER function in Excel), and I think it's because of how I'm coding my method.

[image]

```
def nper(rate, pmt, pv, fv = 0, type = 0)
    a = pmt * (1 + rate * type) + (-1 / rate) * fv
    b = pv * rate + pmt * (1 + rate * type)
    c = Math.sqrt(a / b)
    d = Math.sqrt(1 + rate)
    e = (c / d) * 100
end
```

I tried to calculate parenthesis first, and then using the square root functions in the `Math` module to help calculate the rest.  I'm trying to calculate the periods for a mortgage. Where am I going wrong?

To test, the following:

`nper(((3.5/100)/12), -561.31, 125000)`

Should yield: `~360` (30 year fixed loan)

The rate is divided by 100 and then by 12 because `rate` is the interest rate **per period**.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. That's mathematically impossible. There are no inputs such that the result is a negative number.

Comment: I've tested it in Excel and it resulted in above.  Let's try another figure then (updating).

Answer (score 2):

Using `Math.log10()`, the following formula worked like a charm.  I revised it a tad so I could use a negative version of pmt, and use type and fv (future value).

```
def nper(rate, pmt, pv, fv = 0, type = 0)
  Math.log10((pmt*(1+rate*type)+(-1/rate)*fv)/(pv*rate+pmt*(1+rate*type))) / Math.log10(1 + rate)
end
```

Reference: [MrExcel.com Forum Thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/315095-nper-mathmatical-formula.html)

Answer (score 0):

there is a gem called Exonio: https://github.com/Noverde/exonio which implements some of the Excel financial methods, including the `nper` :

```
Exonio.nper(0.07 / 12, -150, 8000) # ==> 64.07334877066185
```